# Play 2.0 form mapping constraint: Double not supported?

Tags: mapping, double, constraints, playframework-2.0

New to Play, looks like one can apply numeric constraint to Ints and Longs, but not Doubles.

Kind of a show stopper given that case classes with Double properties cannot be bound/unbound; i.e.

```
case class Foo(orderTotal: Double)

// no dice, need a Double but get an Int (same deal with longNumber)
val form = Form(mapping('orderTotal -> number)(Foo.apply)(Foo.unapply) )
```

Anyone got a workaround? Seems like an oversight, no? You'd think that Double would be a fairly common requirement...

Comment: That’s a known limitation of 2.0. It’s fixed in master. A simple workaround consists in implementing a [`Formatter[Double]`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/scala/index.html#play.api.data.format.Formatter)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the workaround Julian. I cloned github repo a few days ago and built against that; was this a very recent addition?

Comment: It was added in [april 2012](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/652d39e50f6cc660437bc680e44b309d1c5ed840#framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/format/Format.scala)

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy actually, this works out of the box (via sbt) when built against master; Scala-IDE, however, is where the error occurs, which is unfortunate, I have to create an implicit val in scope that is a copy of the doubleFormat code block, shame. Also get a compiler error in "routes_routing.scala" on line 22, "value setPrefix is not a member of play.core.Router.Routes", so while the snapshot build works perfectly via sbt, the compromise is 1/2 broken Scala-IDE functionality ;-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see Julian's comment above, resolved in 2.1 snapshot...